# Is there a support contact for the Ubuntu Software Centre purchases?

Tags: software-center

I bought something in the Ubuntu Software Centre and I am getting an error on the install (all of this is automated via Software Centre). Is there someone I can contact about this?

This is for a purchase of Linux Format 158. Notice that the error log mentions Linux Format 157, a different issue. But I get the error even if I delete the issue 157 related file.

Error log:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 1649832 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../lxf158_1.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking lxf158 (1.0-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/lxf158_1.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/opt/futurenet/magazines/data/lxf157.xpm', which is also in package lxf157 1.0-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/lxf158_1.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb
Error in function: { NOTE: this is where the message ends }
```

I followed the suggestion in the comments to "contact the developer". They responded that they have no control over the matter. Since money is being charged on this, there should be some Ubuntu contact to resolve it. Otherwise, they should place a warning: "No refund even if your purchase fails to install".

> Unfortunately we don't have any control over the issues in the
>   software centre, they've been packaged up and licensed away. It
>   certainly looks like someone got confused with issues 157 and 158, but
>   you'd need to communicate with them directly to fix it/get a refund.

**Edit: I was able to get a paypal refund from the email address given in the answer (pay-support@canonical.com). There was a four or five day delay until I heard back, so be patient.**

Comment: Usually package maintainer. What software you were about to install?

Comment: @Michal It was one of the magazines you can buy as a pdf.

Comment: And what kind of error are you getting? Maybe we could solve it here.

Comment: Interesting error. Here is a contact to Linux format http://www.linuxformat.com/contact

Comment: @Michal They responded that they have non control over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[Can I get a refund for my Software Center purchase?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pay/FAQs/Refunds)**
>
> Yes, probably. Please send a copy of your receipt and your reason for requesting a refund to pay-support@canonical.com. Please be detailed; we want to know about any problems so we can fix them and provide you with higher-quality products and services.

---

A refund tends to spark action from the maintainer.

---

Also have look at [My purchase/install failed. How can I get more detail about the error?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pay/FAQs/Get_debug_info):

> **Getting details after an error happened**
>
> If an error only occurred once or you otherwise cannot make it happen again, this is the best way to get data on what happened:

- Run Software Center.
- Attempt to install the failing package in Software Center. Write down each action you take during this process, so there will be enough information to duplicate your steps exactly.
- As soon as the install fails, quit from Software Center.
- Create a bug or support request with a description of what you were trying to do, the details of each step you took, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.
- Attach ~/.cache/software-center/software-center.log to your bug report or support request.
- Attach a copy of your receipt(s) or purchase history to your bug or support request.

Comment: The second link has typos. Maybe create link to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for "Create a bug or support request".

Comment: @Scooter fixed second link